# JQuery Slide Smoothing

Tags: javascript, jquery

The slide animation is not smooth, I googled a bit and found out that I need to set a fixed width for my container but the container's width is set to fill up between 2 other divs.

```
$('.content_block .content_block_title').on("click", function(event) {
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
    var child = $(target).next();

    child.css('width', child.width()); //tried with this but it didnt make the anim smoother.
    if (!child.is(':hidden'))
        child.slideUp(350);
    else
        child.slideDown(150);
});
```

Comment: Nevermind, I had to remove the min-height property I set on the parent container.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!child.is(':hidden'))
        child.animate({    
           height: "350px"
        }, 5000, function() {
           // Animation complete.
        });
    else
        child.animate({    
           height: "150px"
        }, 5000, function() {
          // Animation complete.
        });
```

Comment: use animate function at the place of slide up and slide down